# Get a good sense about the behavior of a power series just by looking at the coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

> How much information we can get about the function $f: [0, R[ \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto  \sum_{ n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ just by looking at  the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ?
>
> For example is it possible to get a good approximation on the shape of the graph of $f$ ? Is it possible to get information about convexity/concavity of the function ?
>
> Also is it possible to get a good approximation of where the local extrema/minima of $f$ are situated in $[0, R[$ ?

I really want to know if all of this can be find just by looking at the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ? So you are not allowed to explicitly compute the function $f$.

For example it's well known that

$$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} x^n.$$

If I just give you the sequence $a_n = -\frac{1}{n}$, is it possible to get a lot of information about $x \mapsto -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}x^n$  so that it's possible to say it's quite logical that this sequence encoded the function $\ln(1-x)$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your concrete example: It should strike you that the (formal, but justifiably correct) derivative is $\sum x^n$, which is well-known to be $\frac1{1-x}$. In that sense, it is "quite logical" that the original encodes $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I suppose that in this case you should explain why the constant sequence : $a_n =1$ encodes $1/(1-x)$ without « manipulations »